# Could not find: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1

Tags: android, firebase

I get the following error while integrating Firebase into my project for the first time.

```
Could not find: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1
```

I followed the steps mentioned on the Firebase documentation, in the section *Add Firebase to your Android Project*, topic Available libraries.

I updated my packages **Google Play Services** (rev 33) and **Google Repository** (rev 32).

What are my options to resolve this error?

Comment: What package you need from firebase?

Comment: you added bulde.gradle apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: @MerlíEscarpenterPérez com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics

Comment: @РоманДервишов yes I added this at the bottom of my app build.gradle apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: this classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3+' bulde.gradle(Project)

Comment: Well then get Google Repository 36.

Comment: Finally you can solve your problem? :)

Comment: I solved the problem!

Comment: Then close your question, thanks and greetings! :)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade you Google Repository to rev 36. `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1` is available from rev 35.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Google Repository is `rev 36`. You can try upgrading; it should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Google Play Services version is the same (9.6.1) and update it also to the newest one or downgrade firebase version to the same:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

Show us your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

**To use firebase analytics you need a few things:**

·**Google play services** package, rev 33

·Add this **classpath** in your *project.gradle*:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

·Add **firebase core** dependencie in *app.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
}
```

·Finally add **pluguin** at final of *app.gradle*:

```
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then you can start to work with Firebase Analytics, you can find more info from sdk [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), apply changes and rebuild project, tell me if you can use it with this changes, greetings!